# Why aren't my comments in my forum saving to the database?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, save

I'm using ruby on rails to create a forum website using a tutorial I found on youtube. I've gotten through 80% of it with no problem till now. I've rewatched the video 10 plus times to ensure no syntax errors or any other mishaps. Basically, comments people make on posts are not saving to the database, and hence they are not showing on the html views where I present them. I know they are not saving because I checked in the terminal the database of comments and it came back as 0 count. Here's my code in the different files...

ROUTES.RB

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users

    resources :posts do 
        resources :comments
    end

    root 'posts#index'
end
```

MIGRATION FILE for create_comments

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
    def change
        create_table :comments do |t|
            t.text :comment
            t.references :post, foreign_key: true
            t.references :user, foreign_key: true

            t.timestamps
        end
    end
end
```

comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:comment))

        if @comment.save
            redirect_to post_path(@post)
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
end
```

_form.html.haml

```
= simple_form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f|
    = f.input :comment
    = f.submit
```

MODEL FILE comment.rb

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :user
end
```

LOG WHEN FORM IS SUBMITTED

```
Started POST "/posts/2/comments" for ::1 at 2016-09-04 23:00:46 +1000
Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/Un6QNWL4BIUbjH5VYMhLRatTq2hokcKnZ3Jb4WzTlvhuZ5AN3gFkA5VHN2E6zsm0iDIx/sKarEfID7Nx4WwwQ==", "comment"=>{"comment"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Comment", "post_id"=>"2"}
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 26ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)



ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template comments/new, application/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/koz/Desktop/forum/app/views"
  * "/Users/koz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/app/views"
):

app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:11:in `create'
  Rendering /Users/koz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/missing_template.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /Users/koz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/koz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (14.6ms)
  Rendering /Users/koz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/koz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (5.4ms)
  Rendering /Users/koz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/koz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/koz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/missing_template.html.erb within rescues/layout (297.8ms)
```

Comment: Can you add the Comment model file? What validations are in it?

Comment: You've actually got two problems here - one, your comments aren't saving, and two, your `Comments#new` view isn't getting found. To solve the second one, can you try changing `render 'new'` to `render :new`?

Comment: I just haven't made the view called 'new' yet

Comment: Okay, fair enough. We still need to see the model file to diagnose your first issue, though.

Comment: doing it now. give me one minute :)

Comment: just added it to the body of the question. have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Comment#create` call is failing because the `Comment` model requires a `User` (`belongs_to` associations come with a presence validation by default), and you're not setting one.

To solve it, set a user.

```
@comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:comment))
@comment.user = current_user
```

(if you're using Devise; otherwise, find your user another way)

Then continue your code as you were (`@comment.save`).

Comment: beautiful. Worked like a charm. Thank you very much. I'm a newbie to this all :)

Comment: @koz Clicking the green checkmark beside an answer allows you to indicate that the answer worked. (You can also upvote, by clicking the up arrow, if you think an answer is useful.)